# Why won't my minipage keep the height with \resizebox?

Tags: minipage, resize

I have three minipages next to each other. They all work as expected, with the top alignment I ask for:

[image: Minipages]

However, when I change the contents of the first minipage to `{\resizebox{1cm}{!}{foo}}`, things go wrong (red box added for clarity):

[image: Minipages]

How can I remedy this? Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{34.5pt}{\resizebox{1cm}{!}{foo}}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{187pt}bar\\bar\\bar
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{34.5pt}bat\\bat\\bat
%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `t` means the alignment is on the baseline of the first row, which is what your image shows: the baseline of foo matches that of the first bar. What output do you want? perhaps add `\vspace{0pt}` as the first thing in each minipage, so they all align on that?

Comment: That works! Please feel free to make it into an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` means the alignment is on the baseline of the first row, which is what your image shows: the baseline of foo matches that of the first bar.

You could add `\vspace{0pt}` as the first thing in each `minipage`, so they all align on that.